# Appium uiviewer image hierachy error the warning tab is not visible after taking screenshot

Tags: appium

I am new to appium, i have used it and its really great.
Recently i tried to work with the swipe functionality. i gone through "http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/11/swipe-element-using-touchaction-class.html " URL but i was unable to find the exact two middle values .In this URL its showing the two values as (457,580). Please tell me how to calculate or get this.

Comment: What middle value? You should provide the essential information in your question and not only refer to a link. Provide code - what you have tried, where you have failed... take a look at how to ask a good question: www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use this and it will work. These x and y will return the x and y location co-ordinates of the devices.

int x =ds.findElements(By.id(id)).getLocation().getX(); 
   int y = ds.findElements(By.id(id)).getLocation().getY();